# Find the maximum number of unique pairs from a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, graph-theory

So I am trying to solve a problem in python and I am able to generate a matrix of the form:

```
[
 [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ],
 [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ],
 [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
 [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ],
 [ 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
]
```

Which is just an array of arrays. The matrix is a square matrix whose diagonal is always going to be 0 because it essentially represents compatibility between two entities. For example, entity 0 is compatible with entity 3, 4, and 5, represented by 1's in the first column. The matrix is mirrored along the diagonal because if entity 1 is compatible with entity 3 then entity 3 will also be compatible with entry 1.

Now what I essentially want to do is find a way that maximum number of compatible entities get paired up, without repetition. For example, if entity 0 has been paired with entity 3, then it should not be paired up with entity 4. However if entity 3 has another compatible entity but entity 4 does not, then entity 0 should be paired with entity 4 and not entity 3.

The end goal is to find out the number of entities that would remain unpaired. I could probably brute force such a solution but since its more of a math problem than a programming one, I would like to know if there is an efficient way of going about it.

Comment: Wouldn't "its more of a math problem than a programming one" suggest this isn't the best site for this question?

Comment: arent most computer science problems actually math problems anyway? The main purpose is to know if there is an efficient algorithm for such a scenario,

Comment: Is this a numpy array? As of now, it's not valid python input. You probably copy-pasted the output of `print(arr)`?

Comment: The array is missing commas. Its just an array of arrays. I'll update the question to fix it

Comment: You're looking for a **maximal marriage** (or **maximal matching**) in an undirected graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears what you have is an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of an undirected graph. Graphs consist of nodes and edges between the nodes. Your problem can be summarized as finding the number of unmatched nodes in a [maximum cardinality matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching). There's networkx API in Python that deals with graphs and if you're willing to use it, the problem becomes very simple.

You first build a graph object from the adjacency matrix; then call [`max_weight_matching`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html) to find the maximum cardinality matching. It implements [Edmonds' blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm).

```py
# pip install networkx
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(data)
tmp = nx.max_weight_matching(G)
```

this outputs the maximum cardinality matching:

```py
{(0, 5), (1, 2), (3, 4)}
```

From there, if you want to find the number of nodes that are unmatched, you can find the difference between the nodes and the matched nodes:

```py
out = len(G.nodes - {x for pair in list(tmp) for x in pair})
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: This really helps a lot. For the current scenario I would prefer not to install any extra packages, however, reading about it landed me on [maximum bipartite matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) which would probably do the job for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @KhizarAmin "maximum bipartite matching" is just the particular case of the problem where the input graph is a bipartite graph. A bipartite graph is a graph where there are two classes of nodes, and edges only exist from one class to the other, not inside a class. For instance, some nodes are "male" and some nodes are "female" and you want to find a matching that only matches males with females but never males with males or females with females.

Comment: Your graph is **not** a bipartite graph, as evidenced by the existence of an odd cycle: 0-3-4. You can't distribute nodes 0, 3 and 4 into "male" and "female" consistently: if 0 is male, then 3 and 4 need to be female, but if 3 is female, then 4 needs to be male, etc.